# Kendo UI Listi View not updating data on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-listview

I am having trouble saving changes using to the server using Kendo UI Listview.

The DataSource is configured like this:

```
var listViewDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: MyServiceURL
            },
            update: function() {
                console.log("test"); // I expected to enter this function 
                                     //  when the user changes data on the 
                                     //client, never happens
            }
        },
        schema: {
            Id: "Id",
            fields: {
                DeptName: {
                    editable: false,
                },
                HourRate: {
                    type: "number",
                    editable: true
                },
                ShowOnSavings: {
                    type: "boolean",
                    editable: true
                },
                ShowOnTechnicalCosts: {
                    type: "boolean",
                    editable: true
                },
                ShowOnOtherCosts: {
                    type: "boolean",
                    editable: true
                }
            }
        },
        sync: function (e) {
            console.log("item synched"); //This should be fired after the 
                                         // updated data is sent, never 
                                         //happens   
        }
```

The ListView is initialised like this:

```
kendo.bind($("#listview-container"), {
        listViewDataSource: listViewDataSource,
        onItemSaved: function (e) {
            console.log("item saved"); // fired every time the user changes 
                                      //an item, as expected 
        }
    })
```

The ListView properly loads the data. When the user edits an item the change is visible locally (after leaving edit mode) and the save event is fired, as expected.

However the changes are never synchronized with the server, my update method is never called and no network activity is never called.

The documentation on the ListView save method states the following:

> Saves edited ListView item. Triggers save event. If save event is not prevented and validation succeeds will call DataSource sync method.

As I don't call `preventDefault`on the save event I expect the data sourve to sync, however this does not happen. Calling `dataSource.sync()` manually does not help either.

I am puzzled why this does not work. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: So far I have my own experience with KendoUI you may need to implement the missing transport-functions also (destroy & create are missing). Also switch the "Id" to "id" in the schema-definition as JavaScript is case-sensitive and the code-behind of the datasource is looking for a property "id". And it may become a problem if your id-field is called "Id" - better change it to something like "entryId".

A workaround would be to handle the communication on your own in the "onItemSaved" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skipped one level of nesting in the model configuration, **model** was missing

```
schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: {
                        type: "number",
                        editable: false
                    },
                    DeptName: {
                        type: "string",
                        editable: false
                    },
                    HourRate: {
                        type: "number",
                        editable: true
                    },
                    ShowOnSavings: {
                        type: "boolean",
                        editable: true
                    },
                    ShowOnTechnicalCosts: {
                        type: "boolean",
                        editable: true
                    },
                    ShowOnOtherCosts: {
                        type: "boolean",
                        editable: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```